# Consider a function that is differentiable on $x \in (0,1)$. Does the function have to be continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

For example, consider $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=s(x)(x+3)$ where $s(x)=0$ if $x=0$ but $s(x)=1$ otherwise. Is the function still differentiable between $x \in (0,1)$, even though it is not continuous at the endpoints. ?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. The derivative of $f$ at a point of $(0,1)$ does not involve the value of $f$ at $0$ so $f$ and the function$x+3$ have the same derivative at $x$, namely $1$.

If you are talking about the right-hand derivative at $0$, NO this derivative does not exist.